# Smart encoding conversion

Tags: linux, encoding

I have a file that contains a mixture of English and Russian lines (one language per line). Russian lines are hand-encoded using one or other [Translit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translit) encodings.

I need to convert Russian translit text to Cyrillic and keep English text intact.

Is there a linux command-line tool that would help me to do that?

Comment: Do you have any means to identify which lines are in English and which in Russian (i.e. odd lines in one language, even in the other)?

Comment: No, languages are distributed more or less at random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to implement this using `sed`, `awk` and such and try to achieve it by command line, but I think it would be more convenient to use Perl an a short script.

You could use the perl module [Lingua::Translit](http://search.cpan.org/~alinke/Lingua-Translit-0.19/lib/Lingua/Translit.pm) to convert lines, and "guess" if the line was in english or not with [Lingua::Identify](http://search.cpan.org/~ambs/Lingua-Identify-0.56/lib/Lingua/Identify.pm).

Here is some code. I did not test it properly, but should give you something to write your own.

```
use Lingua::Translit;
use Lingua::Identify qw(langof set_active_languages);

set_active_languages(qw/ru en/);

my $tr = new Lingua::Translit("ISO 9");

open OUTFILE, ">output.txt" or die $!;
open INFILE, "input.txt" or die $!;
while (my $line = <INFILE>) { 
    my $a = langof($line);
    if ($a eq "ru") {
        my $trline = $tr->translit_reverse($line);
        print OUTFILE $trline;
    } else {
        print OUTFILE $line;
    }
}
close(INFILE);
close(OUTFILE);
```